# Python Error : TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently working on a backup program, I have run into errors while trying to gernate a unique file name with a given destination. I call this function in my code as: getFileUnique(f,pathtofile(backup+"/"+"../trash/")). f is the file path, the rest of the variables are pretty straight forward.

```
def getFileUnique(path,destination):
    path = path.replace("\\","/")
    p = path.split("/")[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(join(destination,p)):
        return destination+p
    j = p.split(".")
    counter = 0
    print(j)
    while os.path.exists(join(destination,j[:-1]+str(counter)+"."+j[-1])):
        print(counter)
        print("asdfsdf")
        counter += 1
    return destination+j[:-1]+str(counter)+"."+j[-1]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Programs\Dev Enviroment\python\backup\backup.py", line 76, in <module>
    main("files","backup")
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Programs\Dev Enviroment\python\backup\backup.py", line 73, in main
    updateBackup(oldf,newf,reg,backup)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Programs\Dev Enviroment\python\backup\backup.py", line 65, in updateBackup
    k = getFileUnique(f,pathtofile(backup+"/"+"../trash/"))
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\Programs\Dev Enviroment\python\backup\backup.py", line 41, in getFileUnique
    while os.path.exists(join(destination,j[:-1]+str(counter)+"."+j[-1])):
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: `j[:-1] + str(counter)` concatenates a list and a string.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, just a little mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
return destination + '.'.join(j[:-1]) + str(counter) + "." + j[-1]
```